# How do you prevent the ::after element from moving your centered text away from the center?

Tags: html, css

How do you prevent the ::after element from moving your centered text away from the center?

```
#pagination div {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#pagination {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#pagination div.number {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  top: -65px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

#pagination div.year {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  color: #c7c7c7;

}

#pagination div.year::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-top: 4px solid #c7c7c7;
  width: 12px;
  float:right;
}

#pagination div.link-wrapper:last-child div.year::after {
  content: none;
  border: none;
}

#pagination div.link-wrapper:last-child div.year {
  left:0px;
}
```

I have this css and everything works fine, except the year element gets moved away from the center because of the ::after element.

I need to add left: 6px; in order to fix this issue, but I am wondering if it might break the page on certain page size, so I was wondering if there was a way to do this without changing the left property for the year div.

```
<body>
    <div id="pagination"><div class="link-wrapper"><div>
    </div><div class="number">4</div><div class="year">2020</div></div><div class="link-wrapper"><div>
    </div><div class="number">4</div><div class="year">2019</div></div><div class="link-wrapper"><div>
    </div><div class="number">3</div><div class="year">2018</div></div></div>
</body>
```

This is the html I am working with.

https://codepen.io/codepen_user_123/pen/vYXMjjX

Comment: You could try adding `margin-right: -6px;` (half of its width) to your `#pagination div.year::after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it position absolute instead if floating it.

```css
#pagination div.year::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 4px solid #c7c7c7;
  width: 12px;

  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```